# PrimeFaces dashboard

Tags: java, jsf, seam, dashboard, primefaces

I saw the PrimeFaces dashboard demo at [DashBoard Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dashboard.jsf). I currently have PrimeFaces 1.1 jar. Will it work or do I have to upgrade to the next version? I am using JSF 1.2 and Seam 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the PrimeFaces showcase is running the latest version, i.e. 2.2.RC2. I know there were bugs with the dashboard component in 2.2.RC1 which have since been fixed in the latest release code.  I would download the most recent and try to make that work.  You can find lots of answers to PrimeFaces questions at their user forum primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do is to update to the last Primefaces version is not that complicated.

You can use this migrations guide to help yourself: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Normally all the dashboard and templates are using the latest version in order to have the last implementations, also to be more compatible.